# The path 'sitemap' is either invalid or you do not have access to it

Tags: navigation

I am attempting to add/link a site map to my main menu. when I enter the path "sitemap" as the "path" for the link to the main menu, I get the following error:

> The path 'sitemap' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

After searching for hours I cannot find a solution. Could someone please help me with a solution?